# Really disable exclusive mode for Bluetooth headphones in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, vmware-horizon

I have disabled exclusive mode for my Bluetooth headset using the following steps:

1. Press <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
2. Type `mmsys.cpl`
3. Click on my headphones device in the list
4. Click the Properties button
5. Select the Advanced tab.
6. Uncheck "Allow applications to take exclusive control of the device"
7. Click OK

However, it doesn't work. System sounds from a remote computer that I am accessing using VMWare Horizon still grab exclusive access to my Bluetooth headphones, and prevent me hearing music that I was listening to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to the difference between A2DP mode (stereo, no microphone) and HFP mode (mono, with microphone). The Bluetooth headset can only be in one mode at once.

It seems the VMWare Horizon application can't really distinguish between wanting to use audio for listening to a system sound and wanting to use audio for the microphone - it just wants to grab both. Which has the side-effect of switching the headset mode from A2DP to HFP.

So in this usage context, these headphones aren't great for listening to music and also using an application which expects the microphone to work, like VMware Horizon (if it is configured to pass microphone input through to the remote compute).

(With small earbud-type headsets, they also have small, low-capacity batteries, so it is also inadvisable to use them for listening to music anyway, as by the time the time comes to use them for a call, they may not have enough battery left to last for a full call!)

The best thing to do is probably to switch to different, dedicated headphones or speakers for listening to music!

Alternatively, if your headphones don't have a microphone, or if you don't want to use their microphone, right-click on the headphones in the Recording tab and choose Disable.